# add uuid column in snowflake table after loading

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a table in snowflake which is already loaded and now we need to add a unique identifier(UUID) column in the table.

We are trying to achieve this by adding a uuid column in snowflake and then updating the value.

```
Alter table xyz add column(uuidx String)

update xyz
Set uuidx = string_uuid()
```

Will it be safe to say all the column value in this new field will be unique. I tested it by updating a table with 999999 record and it came out to be unique. However no where in snowflake document it says how it works. So I am not able to assure it will be unique in any case.

If it is not the safe way then please suggest the best approach

Answer (score 1):

By definition UUIDs are universally unique across space and time. See [UUID - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#:%7E:text=When%20generated%20according,to%20be%20negligible) for more information. [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/uuid_string) assurance is "Generates either a version 4 (random) or version 5 (named) RFC 4122-compliant UUID as a formatted string". The generated UUIDs would not be RFC-4122 compliant if not unique.

Comment: Yes I see that, But could not find any assurance from Snowflake Document That it will be. :)

Comment: Documentation assurance is "Generates either a version 4 (random) or version 5 (named) RFC 4122-compliant UUID as a formatted string". The generated UUIDs would not be RFC-4122 compliant if not unique.